# Search structurally in IntelliJ concatenated methods

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, replace, automation

I'm trying to change some lines (method calls) from many classes with the Search and Replace Structurally feature in IntelliJ (v2016.1.2), the example would be like this:

```
this.method1(param1)
    .method2(param2, param3, param4, param5, true, "")
    .method3();
```

I am also indicating that values of Boolean and string vars are sent by parameter because is part of my problem when editing the variables and finding the method. Therefore i'm hitting some walls:

1. Can't find the method2 by itself, I didn't find the way to reference the boolean and string values
2. Didn't find the way to make a search with concatenated methods. Every method is returning an instance of its own class so I can concatenate them.

This is my first question in stack overflow, so any tips or good practices to improve asking questions is more than welcome :)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you tell more about what it is exactly that you want to do? What change are you trying to make? Is it not enough to search for the method name? Maybe provide a more complete code example if possible?

Answer (score 0):

I made a superclass with a method for those 3 lines, so I can simply call that method in every child class instead of having those 3 methods calls.

I want to go from:

```
Class1Example{
    vars  param1, param2, param3, param4, param5;
    this.method1(param1)
        .method2(param2, param3, param4, param5, true, "")
        .method3();
}
```

To (two classes):

`Class1Example extends SuperClass{
    this.mergingMethod();
}`

```
SuperClass{
    vars  param1, param2, param3, param4, param5;

    void mergingMethod(){
        this.method1(param1)
             .method2(param2, param3, param4, param5, true, "")
             .method3();
    }
}
```

The way I want to do this is using the Search and Replace Structurally in IntelliJ. Also because the scope of it will be of several packages.
I managed to replace this part of the code `method1(param1)`, because the line was found, but when it comes to the line `.method2(param2, param3, param4, param5, true, "")` or the 3 lines themselves the search gives no results. I've read the IntelliJ documentation but I couldn't do it, and google and stackoverflow have no results on this matter.

P.S.: I'm sorry I can't put in here specific code, I hope this can provide better insight in the issue.